# Is there a command for configuring Default apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, file-association

I've written an installer, which associates an extension with my installed program. This is done modifying the registry and this was working fine for previous Windows versions.

For Windows 10 however, there is the "Default apps" feature on top of that, and the problem is that this features seems to be interactive (which I don't want).

Therefore I'm looking for a commandline command that I can use for that (I'm already aware of the `assoc` command but this is not configuring the "Default apps")

Thanks
Dominique

Comment: Altering the registry directly to set file association defaults, is not possible in Windows 10. If you want to deploy file associations, you need to use GPO. Windows 8: [Associate a file Type or protocol with a specific app using GPO](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrmlcgn/2013/02/26/windows-8-associate-a-file-type-or-protocol-with-a-specific-app-using-gpo-e-gdefault-mail-client-for-mailto-protocol/)

Comment: All major programs, such as browsers, are unable to do this in windows 10. They will popup a message telling the user how to change this. I'd say, this is not possible in windows 10 to do automatically and always going to need a little bit of interaction, such as GPO or manual action by the user.